# jQuery .attr Not Working Properly, Miss-Retrieving Links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a page I'm currently working on as a project

```
$(function() {
    $(".modal-launcher, #modal-background").click(function() {
        $(".modal-content, #modal-background").toggleClass("active");
        $(".vid-1i").attr("src", "link1");
        $(".vid-2i").attr("src", "link2");
        $(".vid-3i").attr("src", "link3");
        $(".vid-4i").attr("src", "link4");
        $(".vid-5i").attr("src", "link5");
        $(".vid-6i").attr("src", "link6");
        $(".vid-7i").attr("src", "link7");
        $(".vid-8i").attr("src", "link8");
       //$('html').toggleClass('active').css('top', -(document.documentElement.scrollTop) + 'px');//
    });
});
```

above the actual links are replaced just to display a quick idea of the bad jQuery.

In it, I am attempting to create my own popup launcher for videos; however, I am having trouble using jQuery to replace the "" src of an iframe element to a YouTube link. I am unable to figure out why the jQuery is not working. I understand that the jQuery is, of course, working properly, and that it is me who has written the code incorrectly, but here I am asking if anyone is able to figure out what it is I've done wrong, or what can be changed to make it work.

**For some reason, the last video in the jQuery list is always the one retrieved.**

Understand that the images are missing from the page due to them being local files and not network locations. Clicking above the captions that read like "Match One" will have the "intended" result, regardless if the image is showing or not.

Comment: Try using [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: thanks for the tip, but .prop and .attr appear to yield the same results http://jsfiddle.net/1wsxktj8/1/

Comment: Your html has invalid nestlings.  You have many span's that aren't closed.  It may be a factor into incorrect DOM traversing to find proper elements.

Comment: That I do, thank you; however, after updating the HTML, the problem persists http://jsfiddle.net/1wsxktj8/2/

Answer (score 0):

Coming back to this and understanding more of JavaScript and jQuery, my problem was simply misunderstanding the code. In order to do something like this, one function per link would be more suitable.

```
function video1()
{
    $("#popup, #modal-background").toggleClass("active");
    $("#popup").prop("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/7h1s15n74r3all1nk");
    document.getElementById('scroll').style.cssText ='overflow:hidden';
}
```

complementary html would look like this:

```
<div onclick="video1()"></div>
```

The previous code would run each line, effectively setting the last link as the source of the element. The new code is button independent, ensuring only one link belongs to each button.